# Trying to Delete table row through ajax, code igniter but it's not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to delete products added in the cart individually and also whole cart when clicking. I have two **scenarios** If user is logged in or not. In both scenarios when I delete single row it deleted but when I reload my page the row appears again. **Data is perfectly Deleted from database**, but in the Front End It's not working, but it is working fine in case of deleting whole cart. Where is the problem in **jQuery** or **PHP**. The View of My cart is:

[image: Here is the View of My cart]

Here is the code of Delete Function in **Jquery**

```
    $(document).on('click' , '.delBtn' , function(){
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');
    alert(rowId)
    var thisElement = $(this);
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You want to delete the domain from your cart!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      cancelButtonClass: "btn-warning",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
      if(isConfirm) {
            alert("yes");
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : base_url+'home/remove',
                data    : {id:rowId},
                beforeSend : function(){

                },
                success : function(data){
                    alert(data)
                    if(data == 'true'){
                        swal({
                            type : 'success',
                            title : "Done!",
                            text    : "Domain Deleted From your Cart!",
                            timer: 2000,
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                        var total_item = $('.total_items').html();
                        $('.total_items').html(parseInt(total_item)-1);
                        thisElement.closest('tr').remove();
                        var sum_value = update();
                        if(sum_value == 0) {
                            $('.view_cart_table').remove();
                            $('h2.empty').html('Your Cart is empty.');  
                        }else{
                            $('.total_amount span').html(sum_value);
                        }

                    }
                    if(data == 'all'){
                        swal({
                            type : 'success',
                            title : "Done!",
                            text    : "Your Cart is Empty Now!",
                            timer: 2000,
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                        var total_item = $('.total_items').html();
                        $('.total_items').html(total_item-total_item);
                        $('.view_cart_table').remove();
                        $('h2.empty').html('Your Cart is empty.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In Data Its Return data value but when I reload my page It appears again

Here is the **Php Code igniter** Code

```
    public function remove(){ /* This Function is for Removing domains From cart Whole and individually */
        $rowid = $this->input->post('id');
        if($this->session->userdata('users_Data')){
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata['users_Data']['user_id'];
        }else{
            $user_id = '';
        }
        if($rowid === ''.$user_id.'all'){
            $this->main_model->del_all_cart($user_id);
            $this->cart->destroy();
            echo "all";
        }else if($rowid === 'all'){
            $this->cart->destroy();
            echo "all";
        }else{
            if($user_id == ''){
                $data = array(
                'id' => $rowid,
                'qty' => 0
                );
                $this->cart->update($data);
                echo "true";
            }else{
                $this->main_model->del_single_cart($rowid);
                $data = array(
                'id' => $rowid,
                'qty' => 0
                );
                $this->cart->update($data);
                echo "true";
            }
        }

    }
```

**Can Anyone help??????**

Comment: Use this 
$this->cart->remove($rowid);  // for removing single row delete

Comment: It's done I was using this 'id' => $row id, Id saved in the Database but for remove or update we have to use row id which is by default id given by the Cart class  that's why it was not working

Comment: thisElement.remove(); should do. You've already grabbed the tr you want to remove.